# Adding link with image in the .tpl.php file

Tags: 7, forms

I have just started with drupal and have very little understanding and experience with it. I was able to develop a module by referring to sample modules available online. I have a .tpl.php file that is supposed to have a link in the form of an image, I am hoping to execute a php function (php function is ready) by clicking on that image. 
So my question is how to add a link inside the .tpl.php file, do I have to implement a form? if so, what file should have this form? How to execute the php function on click from this link?

Please let me know if the question doesn't make enough sense.

Thanks

Comment: since PHP is a server side script, I don't believe you can execute a php function once the page is loaded, unless you make a POST or GET call to another file. Do you want to hard-code this link?  if that's the case, then it works no different than any other html tag, just decide where you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is something to link to that will execute your PHP "callback". Have a look at [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) in the Drupal API.

Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MODULENAME_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['mymodule/callback'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'MODULENAME_do_callback',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), // You can specify a permission here.
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function MODULENAME_do_callback() {
  // your php here
}
```

With that you should be able to link your image (just with standard HTML) to yourdomain.com/mymodule/callback and it will execute your code.

Note: Be sure to clear all caches after adding your `hook_menu()` implementation.